# How to spell [kæʃt] in the sense of "expended"

Tags: meaning, orthography, slang

I have Googled but can't even find this word sense in online dictionaries. I've heard the word [kæʃt] used in the sense of "expended", such as in the following examples:

> My drink is [kæʃt]. (*implying that it is empty*)
>
> The bowl is [kæʃt]. (*implying there is no more marijuana*)

I assume it would be spelled "cashed" (and may have an etymological relationship to "cashing out" at a casino) or "cached", but I am not sure. How is it spelled? Also, please offer a definition of this term if my usage is incorrect (the above two examples are the only contexts in which I've heard it used—perhaps it is only used in reference to alcohol and drugs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is spelled ***cashed***.

From *McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions*, via [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cashed):

> **cashed**
>   1. *mod*. expired; depleted; burnt out. (From cashed in.)
>
> *My pen is cashed. Where can I get a new one?*
>     
>   2. *mod*. tired.
>
> *Man, I’m cashed. Can we rest here for a while?*

[Wiktionary backs up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cashed#Adjective) this sense of *cashed* (again, with an `s`, not another `c`), using precisely your alcohol and marijuana examples:

> **cashed** ‎(*comparative* more cashed, *superlative* most cashed)
>   (*slang*) Exhausted or used up; finished, empty.
>
> *That bowl [of marijuana] is cashed.*
>   *Hand me another beer. This one is cashed.*

And it seems the slang has crept into the jargon of certain subcultures. For example, from *[The Dictionary of Mountain Bike Slang](http://world.std.com/~Jimf/biking/slang.html)*:

> **cashed** adj. to be too tired to ride any farther; bonked.

Comment: @Dan Sure, no problem. Like I told you before, we Dans have to stick together.  Lemme know if you refill the bowl...